# Attendee Availability or Unvailability

Tags: grammar

Which one of these is correct?

Rescheduling due to attendee unavailability OR

Rescheduling due to attendee availability

Comment: The first one is correct.

Comment: I agree, you are rescheduling because an attendee is unavailable not because an attendee is available.  Lack of attendee availability would be more difficult to reason away.

Comment: I *disagree*. I think both are fine. Same as [Cocktail Reception Program and speakers subject to change due to speaker availability](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22Cocktail+Reception+Program+and+speakers+subject+to+change+due+to+speaker+availability%22), where it's obviously far more likely things will change because a speaker is ***unavailable*** rather than because he is available. You could always understand it as shorthand for ***level of** availability* (where the level is implicitly "inadequate, too low, non-existent").